# Nasm assembly. Can't move a value to a local variable on the stack

Tags: assembly, nasm

I tried to write a procedure that returns greatest value in a word array.
I've allocated local variable by convention listed [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html).
But when I try to move a value in local variable it gives me this error:

`invalid combination of opcode and operands`

Here is my code:

```
greatest:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
                        ;allocate local variables here
    sub esp, 4
                        ;push stuff
    push esi

    mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ;size of the array
    mov eax, [ebp+8]    ;offset of the array
    mov esi, 0          ;counter for accessing elements
    mov ebp-4, eax      ;error here 
l1:
    push ecx 
    mov ecx, [eax + 2*esi] ;get the variable
    cmp [ecx], [ebp-4]     ;compare values
    jb if_2                 
    mov ebp-4, ecx      ;error here
if_2:
    inc esi
    pop ecx
    loop l1

    mov eax, [ebp-4]

    pop esi
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `cmp [ecx], [ebp-4]` you cannot compare mem with mem

Comment: @Alexander Zhak But it is in registry, right? And compiler doesn't seem to care. I want to note that in a given link MASM is used and there `mov ebp-4, eax` works fine. In NASM it doesn't seem to. It probably has to do with syntax for memory and value addressing.

Comment: My MASM refuses to assemble `mov ebp-4, eax`. "*error A2032:invalid use of register*".

Comment: @KyleButler  `ecx` means value (address) in register; `[ecx]` means value, which is stored at address in register. Once you understand this, other things will become easy

Comment: [Differences Between MASM and NASM](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/mp/f99/mp5/masm_nasm.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problems in your code are with the difference between surrounding things by `[]` and not.

On the lines indicated by `nasm`, the issue is not having brackets.  `ebp - 4` is a location in memory that you want to store the data to, so you have to surround it with brackets.

Another issue is with the line `cmp [ecx], [ebp - 4]`.  This won't compile because it's trying to compare two different items in memory, at locations `ecx` and `ebp - 4`, and you can't do it with two different memory things (at least one has to be a register / constant).

However, this is not really what you would like to do anyway.  Because `ecx` stores the *value*, not the *location*, you really want `cmp ecx, [ebp - 4]`.  This is correct.

Once you change these things, your code will compile.  However, it will not run correctly.  While `nasm` likes it, there are still issues with brackets vs no brackets.

The last issue I see is, again, with the `mov [ebp - 4], eax` (previously `mov ebp - 4, eax`) line.  While `eax` contains the offset (address) of the list, and therefore the address of the first element, it does not contain that element itself, so it, too, must be surrounded with brackets.

However, just writing `mov [ebp - 4], [eax]` produces a similar error to before: `nasm` yells at you because you can't have two memory things in it.

We can fix this by using a register (e.g. `esi`) as a temporary storage. (I chose `esi` because we're overwriting it anyway, so we don't have to store it on the stack.)  So this becomes:

```
mov esi, [eax]
mov [ebp-4], esi
mov esi, 0        ; moved this line from above so it's still 0 at the end
```

So all in all, with the changes this becomes:

```
greatest:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
                        ;allocate local variables here
    sub esp, 4
                        ;push stuff
    push esi

    mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ;size of the array
    mov eax, [ebp+8]    ;offset of the array
    mov esi, [eax]      ;store in esi temporarily 
    mov [ebp-4], esi    ;now we can move it to the local variable
    mov esi, 0          ;counter for accessing elements

l1:
    push ecx 
    mov ecx, [eax + 2*esi] ;get the item from the list
    cmp ecx, [ebp-4]       ;compare values
    jb if_2                 
    mov [ebp-4], ecx     
if_2:
    inc esi
    pop ecx
    loop l1

    mov eax, [ebp-4]

    pop esi
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks! That really shed some light on memory/registry handling. I got all confused with different syntax of MASM and NASM memory accessing and forgot where what actually is stored. The answer is very useful. Thanks again!